# GUI doesn't appear in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea, jframe

I'm learning *Java* along with *IntelliJ IDEA*. I want to try the Celsius converter explained in Oracle tutorial so I did the following steps:

- Created a new GUI form.
- Created a class called `CelsiusConverterGUI`.

It says that the form is automatically bind to the *CelsiusConverterGUI.java*.

Below is the `CelsiusConverterGUI` class declaration:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class CelsiusConverterGUI extends Frame{
  private JTextField celsiusDegree;
  private JButton convertButton;
  private JLabel fahrenheitDeg;
  private JPanel panel;

  public CelsiusConverterGUI(){
    setVisible(true);
    convertButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int fahrDegree = (int)(Double.parseDouble(celsiusDegree.getText()));
        fahrenheitDeg.setText(fahrDegree+"Fahrenheit");
      }
    });
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    new CelsiusConverterGUI();
  }
}
```

When I run it, a *Java* application window pops up hodling only the menu bar default icons (**x** **-** **+**), and doesn't show the panel or buttons I created in the GUI form.

Can anyone explain why does it behave so?

Answer (score 2):

Problems:

- You're extending the AWT Frame class not the Swing JFrame class
- You've added nothing to your GUI. In your constructor you should add components to your JPanel and add that to your JFrame **before** setting it visible.
- You need to go through the Swing tutorials which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing).
- My recommendation when learning a new library -- avoid code generation tools and instead learn to code it by hand as this will give you a better foundation for understanding the libraries internals.
- You're learning a new library and it will be difficult while you're just starting out, but keep at it, avoid guessing by reading the tutorials, and it will come.

Comment: But as my understanding, once I created the GUI form, all the elements like buttons or panel should have be bounded to my class, right? Because I think, if I added these components again in my constructor, then the GUI will be different from the one I created in the GUI form, since the size and position of these components will be reset.

Comment: @zhang_rick: I am not familiar with IntelliJ's Swing code generation tools, but regardless, I advise you to not use the GUI builder. Code it by hand using the better sections of the tutorial for this as a guide.

Answer (score 1):

@Hovercraft has already tackled the main issues, and I would only add that you are missing your GUI component initialization that will certainly lead to a `NullPointerException` once you get your frame visual and functional:

- You are calling the `getText()` method on your `celsiusDegree` text field:

  ```
  int fahrDegree = (int)(Double.parseDouble(celsiusDegree.getText()));
  ```
- While you have only declared that instance field without initialization:

  ```
  private JTextField celsiusDegree;
  ```

Here down a correct version of your class that fixes down main issues from @Hovercraft answer and my additional note:

package org.wisebrains.thirdparty.gui;

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class CelsiusConverterGUI extends JFrame{
  private JTextField celsiusDegree;
  private JButton convertButton;
  private JLabel fahrenheitDeg;
  private JPanel panel;

  public CelsiusConverterGUI(){
    // GUI Components Initialization
    convertButton = new JButton("Convert");
    celsiusDegree = new JTextField("");
    panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    fahrenheitDeg = new JLabel();
    //...
    convertButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int fahrDegree = (int)(Double.parseDouble(celsiusDegree.getText()));
        fahrenheitDeg.setText(fahrDegree + " Fahrenheit");
      }
    });
    // Adding your GUI Components to the main panel then to the frame
    panel.add(convertButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(celsiusDegree, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(fahrenheitDeg, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.add(panel);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(300,200);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }


  public static void main(String[] args){
    new CelsiusConverterGUI();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is the way to create GUI without the GUI form. I want to use the GUI form, instead of setting up all the components and their properties by writing codes by hand. I definitely agree that this way is worth learning. But I really want to know why the GUI form way doesn't work.

Comment: (PS: the declarations of the components in my code are not just declarations, they are actually generated automatically after I create the GUI form in another tab. The GUI form has its only source code generated by the IDE, to set up the properties of the components.And intelliJ indicates that the GUI form is bound to the class already)

Answer (score 1):

you miss add content panel

Below is the `CelsiusConverterGUI` class declaration:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class CelsiusConverterGUI extends Frame{
  private JTextField celsiusDegree;
  private JButton convertButton;
  private JLabel fahrenheitDeg;
  private JPanel panel;

  public CelsiusConverterGUI(){
    super("CelsiusConverterGUI");//name of you program
    setSize(400,500);//size of this
    setContentPane(panel);//to show you content(you miss it)
    pack();//set content the same design in GUI
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//close form to exte
    setVisible(true);
    convertButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int fahrDegree = (int)(Double.parseDouble(celsiusDegree.getText()));
        fahrenheitDeg.setText(fahrDegree+"Fahrenheit");
      }
    });
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    new CelsiusConverterGUI();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just looked into the tutorial of IntelliJ IDEA for GUI form, and I found the solution to my problem, by editing the main() method.

Here's the code:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


    public class CelsiusConverterGUI{
        private JTextField celsiusDegree;
        private JButton convertButton;
        private JLabel fahrenheitDeg;
        private JPanel panel;
        private JLabel celsiusLabel;


        public CelsiusConverterGUI(){


            convertButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int fahrDegree = (int)(Double.parseDouble(celsiusDegree.getText())*1.8+32);
                    fahrenheitDeg.setText(fahrDegree+" Fahrenheit");
                }
            });

        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("CelsiusConverterGUI");
            frame.setContentPane(new CelsiusConverterGUI().panel);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

    }
```

Compared to my original code, the new one adds the JFrame frame, the setContentPane, and the default close operation.

Now my understanding is that, I indeed don't need to initialise the components that I created in the GUI form. But I do need to create the JFrame frame to make the GUI form functional.